# AWS RDS Multi-AZ did not fail over during master patching up

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, failover

RDS - MySQL

We recently had a database outage due to a minor engine version upgrade.

We have RDS multi AZ setup. I can clearly see in master instance that that is saying Multi AZ yes and it is in a different availability zone.

In master I see events as

DB instance has a DB engine update

backing up DB

Finished backup

DB instance shut down

DB instance resumed

In the replica I am also seeing an event at the time of the incident

"Slave is disconnected from the master and is attempting to reconnect.

I have also seen in  following event in replica prior to incident

"The free storage for DB instance  is low at 5%."

I am trying to understand why didn't master failover to standby  during the DB instance patched up.

What would be the issue? how can I find out why the failover didn't happen?

Answer (score 2):

Was this MySQL?

If so, see [Will a Multi-AZ deployment help reduce downtime during an Amazon RDS MySQL modification?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-mysql-downtime-impact/)

> Because RDS MySQL doesn’t automate rolling upgrades, the DB engine version upgrade happens to both the primary and standby hosts at the same time. Therefore, a DB engine version upgrade doesn't benefit from a Multi-AZ deployment.

Also, see [Best Practices for Upgrading Amazon RDS for MySQL and Amazon RDS for MariaDB](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-upgrading-amazon-rds-for-mysql-and-amazon-rds-for-mariadb/):

> One common fallacy is that Multi-AZ configurations prevents downtime during an upgrade. We do recommend that you use Multi-AZ for high availability, because it can prevent extended downtime due to hardware failure or a network outage. However, in the case of a MySQL or MariaDB engine upgrade, Multi-AZ doesn’t eliminate downtime. The slow shutdown and the physical changes made on the active server by the mysql_upgrade program require this downtime.

Comment: yes this is MySQL